# Easy way to show Decimal of Long via CountDownTimer - Android

Tags: java, android, decimal, long-integer, countdown

I have working code but it seems a bit strange that I have to gimmick my way around showing a decimal place on CountDownTimer but I haven't found anything that does it easier (obviously).

Here is the working Code I currently have:

```
    final String tempTitle = TextView.getText().toString();

    new CountDownTimer(10000, 100) {

                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                     String timeDown = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 100);
                     String secTime="0";
                     String sec10th="0";
                     if (Long.valueOf(millisUntilFinished) < 1000) {
                     secTime ="0";
                     sec10th = timeDown.substring(0,1);
                     }else{
                     secTime=timeDown.substring(0,1);
                     sec10th = timeDown.substring(1,2);
                     }

                     TextView.setText("Start in: " + secTime + "." + sec10th);
                 }

                 public void onFinish() {
                     TextView.setText(tempTitle);
                 }
              }.start(); 


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

divide by 100.0 so you dont do integer division.

Edit per your comment:
 you could do

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#.##"); //import java.text.DecimalFormat;
String timeDown=df.format(millisUntilFinished/100.0);
```

or #.### etc depending on how many decimals you want...

Comment: Thanks, works good, not getting even division on the 100s and 1000s so I'm using .substring(0,3) to get the #.#, is there a better number format to throw in? Before I convert to String?